# Question about automorphisms of the cyclotomic field and Sagemath

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ be the fifth cyclotomic field. I write the following code in sage

```
K.<z> = CyclotomicField(5)
L.<a1> = K.galois_closure()
for i in L.galois_group():
    print i
```

which returns

```
()
(1,2,3,4)
(1,3)(2,4)
(1,4,3,2)
```

as the automorphisms of $K$. However, the automorphisms must be given by $$\sigma_k: \zeta_5 \mapsto \zeta_5^k $$ for $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and for $k = 2$, I get the following result:
$$\zeta_5 \mapsto\zeta_5^2 \mapsto \zeta_5^4 \mapsto \zeta_5^3.$$ Thus, I end up with the permutation $(1243)$ which does not appear in the Sage output. What is the point that I am missing here?

Comment: Probably the roots are not numbered as you think they are. The representation of the Galois group is only well-defined up to conjugation, ocrresponding to a relabelling of the roots.

Comment: But even if the numbering is different, the cycle types must be same right? For example I cannot get any two cycles like $(13)(24)$ that the Sage says

Comment: Sure you can, $(1243)^2=(14)(23)$.

Comment: No I mean with $\sigma_k$ as above, I end up with $\text{id},(1243),(1342),(23)$. So even if I the labeling is different, how can do I end up with two disjoint two cycles from those above? ($\text{id},(1243),(1342),(23)$)

Comment: It is not possible to end up with what you said, because that is not a group. This means you made a mistake at some point. It should be $(14)(23)$ and not $(23)$, assuming $(1243)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider the sage objects in detail:

```
sage: K.<z> = CyclotomicField(5)
sage: K.is_galois()
True
```

So there is no need to take the Galois closure. Well, doing so we get some `a1` which differs from `z`, let us compare:

```
sage: L.<a1> = K.galois_closure()
sage: a1.complex_embedding()
-0.809016994374947 - 0.587785252292473*I
sage: z.complex_embedding()
0.309016994374947 + 0.951056516295154*I
sage: a1.minpoly()
x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
sage: z.minpoly()
x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
```

OK, now let us consider the Galois group of $K$, its elements and their action on $z$:

```
sage: for s in K.galois_group():
....:     print(f"{str(s):10} maps z to {s(z)}")
....: 
()         maps z to z
(1,2,3,4)  maps z to z^2
(1,3)(2,4) maps z to -z^3 - z^2 - z - 1
(1,4,3,2)  maps z to z^3
```

The cyclotomic unit $z=\zeta_5$ comes with the usual complex embedding
$
\cos\frac {2\pi}5 +
i\sin\frac {2\pi}5
$, and the generator $(1234)$ of the Galois group maps $z$ to $z^2$, and the full chain is
$$
z\to z^2\to z^4\to z^8=z^3\to z^{16}=z\ .
$$
This corresponds to the permutation, written as a cycle:
$$
(z,z^2,z^4,z^3)\ .
$$
Now write instead of $z,z^2,z^4,z^3$ formally the symbols $1,2,3,4$.

In general, the elements of a Galois group of some Galois field $K$ are realized as permutations of the set of roots of the defining polynomial of $K$. (In case of a non-normal $K$, we pass to the Galois closure $L$, use the defining polynomial of $L$.)